# Send an image from AWS S3 to IBM Watson Visual Recognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, watson

I am trying to send images stored on Amazon S3 storage to IBM Watson Visual Recognition Service.

The error i am getting is `Error: Invalid JSON content received. Unable to parse.`

The following code is running on an Express server.

```
function (imgResult) {
          var imgName = imgResult[0][0].imghash;
          var params = {
            images_file: s3.getObject(
              {
                Bucket: "Bucket Address",
                Key: `upload/${imgName}`
              }
            ).createReadStream()
          };
          visual_recognition.classify(params, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              res.images[0].classifiers[0].classes.forEach(function (tagClass) {

                db.raw(`INSERT INTO smartfolio.tags VALUES (null, ${imgid.idimages}, '${tagClass.class}')`)
                  .then(function (results) {
                  })
                  .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                  })
              });
            }
          });
        }
```

In the code above, imgResult is a response from a database query, containing the images name from the database. I know the problem lies in my params variable, but I am kind of lost on how to send the image from S3 to Watson.

The error:

```
{ Error: Invalid JSON content received. Unable to parse.
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\pheon\Desktop\Smartfolio-1\node_modules\watson-developer-cloud\lib\requestwrapper.js:74:15)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\pheon\Desktop\Smartfolio-1\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pheon\Desktop\Smartfolio-1\node_modules\request\request.js:1081:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pheon\Desktop\Smartfolio-1\node_modules\request\request.js:1001:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the JSON that's being reported as invalid?  The seemingly obvious first step is to examine it.

Comment: Where is the JSON?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot there is no JSON, there is an image file that lies on S3 storage. and I am trying to stream it form s3 to Watson . So I don't know what JSON is this referring to.

Comment: FYI, AWS also has an image recognition service that works with Amazon S3: [Amazon Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably related to a recent issue in the Python SDK, which had the same error message:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/pull/241

Solutions:

1. The multipart-encoded file content_type needs to be application/zip when sending to VR
2. Replaced windows path which throws json parsing errors.

---

It seems that the same issue is still existent in the Node SDK. 
Looking at line 289 the content type is also set to *application/json*

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/visual-recognition/v3.js

Maybe you implement a test for a zip file in the SDK and change the content typ to application/zip or open an issue in the Node SDK repo.